# iPhone: Play sound when app moves to background

Tags: iphone, audio, background, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a sound when the app is moving to the background.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *goodByeSoundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoodBye" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *goodByeSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:goodByeSoundUrl error:&error];
    [goodByeSound play];
}
```

This code won't work on my device (iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0). But it does work on the Simulator.
If i add the following line to the Info.plist it is playing the sound, but there is a red bar on the homescreen indicating that the app is still active in the background.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Actually that is not what I want. I just want the sound to be played and I don't need the app to be active in the background all the time.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add these three lines in your code:-

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW79)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, since when your app is pushed to the background all audio your is producing will be muted.

Adding the background mode will not work since this is only for audio players.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```